# A few objects into one Array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a problem with adding new Object to the Array of Objects.
Look:

```
 A.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(M, 8) };
```

It is a sample, where Edge[] consists of one Object. But I don't know how much objects will Edge[] consits, because I am taking the number from File. I took "vertexes" from file to vertex[], and wages from file to wages[].
The file looks like:

```
1 2 3
3 4 5
3 2 1
4 56 7
2 3 5 
5 2 1
```

First and second number from each line is vertex, third one is wage.

I have written a code like this:

```
    Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[N];

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        vertices[i] = new Vertex(i);

    int w_1 = Vertex[0], w_2 = 0, wage = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<Vertex.length; i++) {
    if(Vertex[i] == w_1) {
        if(i%2 == 0) {
        if(wage == 0) wage = Wage[i/2];
        if(i%2 == 0) {
        for(int f=0; f<vertices.length; f++)
            if(vertices[f].name == i) {
                for(int l=0; l<vertices.length; l++) 
                    if(vertices[l].name == Vertex[i+1])
            vertices[f].adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(vertices[l], wage) };
            }
        }

        if(i%2 != 0) {
            for(int f=0; f<vertices.length; f++)
                if(vertices[f].name == i) {
                    for(int l=0; l<vertices.length; l++) 
                        if(vertices[l].name == Vertex[i-1])
                    vertices[f].adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(vertices[l], wage) };
        }
        w_1 = i;

        int temp = Wage[i/2];
        if(temp < wage) { 
            wage = temp;
            if(i%2 == 0) 
                w_2 = Vertex[i+1];
            if(i%2 != 0) 
                w_2 = Vertex[i-1];
        }
        }
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem, to insert a few Objects into one Array not knowing how many Objects will be there? :) I cant use ArrayList.

Comment: Why can't you, for performance problems?

Comment: Because then the rest of code does not work properly.

Comment: Learn how to use Lists.

Comment: It seems that you are reinventing the wheel of ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have created an

```
List<Vertext> vertexList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and added stuff without worrying about a limit, you can

```
Vertex[] vertexArray = vertexList.toArray( new Vertex[vertexList.size()] );
```

and all will work.

(For the future: basing code on arrays has disadvantages as compared to List - as you have noticed now.)

Comment: Indeed. The easiest way is to work with an arraylist as long as you don't know the final size and at the end convert the list to an array using `vertexList.toArray()` (no parameters required).

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
A.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(M, 8) };
```

creates array of size 1. Size of array is determined when array is created, and cannot be changed later. You could create new array and copy elements from old array to new one if you need to. (That is rough description of ArrayList implementation).

If you know size of your array in advance, just do

A.adjacencies = new Edge[size];
  A.adjacencies[0]=new Edge(M, 8);
  ...
  A.adjacencies[size-1]=new Edge(M, whatever);

Because you read from file, you should know size of your data structure. Most file formats store size of dynamic structure first, then elements of the structure.

If you do not know size of your structure in advance, then dynamic data structure ([java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) , in your case) is only reasonable choice.